# Reshaping and Transpose issues

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

User1190882 has helped fix the tranpose issue. I will open a new thread for the SKlearn issue.

```
columns_train = np.array([df['A'], df['B'],  df['C'], df['D'], df['E'], df['F'], df['G']])
X = columns_train
Y = columns_target

X = np.transpose(X)
print np.shape(X)
print np.shape(Y)


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

clf = svm.LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print clf

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 172, in check_classification_targets
raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

I am not sure what I can do to make this work after looking at other threads. Can you give me some advise please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to before editing question**

What you are looking for is

```
X = np.transpose(X)
```

**Answer after editing question**

You get that `continuous` error when your datatype of your variable `Y` is of floating point type. In all classification type of problems, you have to maintain the label type as `int`. Convert the datatype of variable Y to `int` and then it should work fine.

Comment: I have edited the question because there is another issue here, because this question consist of multiple issues

Comment: Added the solution to your new problem. Please don't edit questions in the manner in which you have done as you have posted a new problem altogether. If you wish to post the new problem, please append it to the question already posted or else post a new question but please never overwrite it.

Comment: Yes I thought about it, what I did was not correct as it will confuse people, I will now recreate another question on the other issue instead thanks for your advise